# Trouble Displaying Image From A GridView

Tags: android, gridview

I'm trying to implement a GridView that displays several images similar to this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

In addition to the link above, I'm also following this short tutorial: http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/gridview-tutorial-using-the-picasso-library.html

I'm able to display the images in the GridView within main activity, however, my trouble lies within my second activity, the one where I'm trying to display the image from the GridView into an ImageView on the second activity.

More specifically, the trouble lies on this line of code (with mThumbIds):

```
Picasso.with(MovieDetails.this).load(MainActivity.mThumbIds[position]).into(imageView);
```

I've tried and tried several different things, but can't figure out how I can correct the "`'cannot resolve symbol 'mThumbIds'`" error. Any help would be much appreciated.

MainActivity -

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MovieDetails.class);
                intent.putExtra("Position", position);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        public Context mContext;

        public ImageAdapter(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mThumbIds.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return mThumbIds[position];
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {

                imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
            } else {

                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }

            Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(mThumbIds[position]).noFade().into(imageView);
            return imageView;
        }

        // references to our images
        public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
                .... ref to my images 
        };

    }

}
```

Second Activity -

```
public class MovieDetails extends MainActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_movie_details);

        int position = getIntent().getIntExtra("position", -1);

        if (position != -1) {
            Picasso.with(MovieDetails.this).load(MainActivity.mThumbIds[position]).into(imageView);
        } else {
            Picasso.with(MovieDetails.this).load(R.drawable.sample_7).into(imageView);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, basic Java here

you declared:

`public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
                .... ref to my images 
 };`

This is instance variable in `MainActivity`

While you access this variable as `static` variable in SecondActivity.

Should have declared `mThumbIds` as static (even though I don't recommend doing this as best practice in Android development).

Answer (score 1):

We can access only static variable from other class, and your variable mThumbIds is non-static variable.

One more thing you declare your variable inside Adapter class and try to access from MainActivity.java

Try to move your variable to MainActivity.java and make the variable as static and access from other class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public ImageView imageView;

    // references to our images
    public static Integer[] mThumbIds = {};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MovieDetails.class);
                intent.putExtra("Position", position);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        public Context mContext;

        public ImageAdapter(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mThumbIds.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return mThumbIds[position];
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {

                imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
            } else {

                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }

            Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(mThumbIds[position]).noFade().into(imageView);
            return imageView;
        }


    }

}
```